# Dar formato de moneda, Laravel chats 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, chart.js

por mucho que busque no encuentro como darle el formato de moneda a los importes laterales que salen de la gráfica. Todo lo que encuentro está en JavaScript y no se como hacerlo en el controlador de Laravel.

Esto lo tengo en el controlador de Laravel.

```
$chart->dataset('Ventas:', 'bar', array_values($result))
      ->color("#3d3d3d")
      ->backgroundcolor("rgba(111, 216, 205, 0.54)")
      ->options([
            'borderWidth' => 1,
                        
      ]);
```

Y lo que encuentro que se puede hacer es así:

```
 scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          if(parseInt(value) >= 1000){
            return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
          } else {
            return '$' + value;
          }
        }
      }
    }]
  }
```

Pero no se como incorporar esto en laravel, como veis aquí está en $ pero siria ponerlo en €.

Comment: Imagino que como no puedes hacerlo desde front, estás usando algún paquete en laravel para los charts, qué paquete usas?

Comment: Hola @L.Flor si estoy usando este paquete que se instala con composer: `consoletvs/charts:6.*` se hace todo desde el controlador